# Github webpages external css not working but js work fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

### Background Information

I have a webpage with 10 subpages, which use the same basic HTML and CSS.

The first 5 pages have this code in the `<head>` section:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./MainConfig/MAINCSS.css">
<script language="javascript" src="./MainConfig/Copyrights.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./JS/CL.js"></script>
```

...and the other 5 have the same:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../MainConfig/MAINCSS.css">
<script language="javascript" src="../MainConfig/Copyrights.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/CL.js"></script>
```

---

### Problem

However, the CSS is not working. Strangely, many people have had the same problem. Despite searching **css not working in gitwebpages**, the only results I have found were about mistyping the location or using `\` insted of `/`.

The JavaScript is working fine but the CSS is not. Also, it works fine in localhost.

**Any thought on this?** *Thanks in advance!*

---

## Extra Information

### File structure

```
Root
 |
 +----- readme.md
 |
 +----- index.html
 |
 +----- GrLang
 |
 +----- EnLang
 |
 +----- img
 |
 +----- JS
 |       |
 |       +----- CL.js
 |
 +----- MainConfig
            |
            +----- MAINCSS.css
            |
            +----- Copyrights.js
```

---

### Error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Please can you add your file structure. Also, in the DevTools, does it come up with any errors?

Comment: I have a main folder of the webpage which includes the index.html,readme, and 4 folders (GrLang,EnLang,img,js and main config)

The index html goes directly to mainconfig  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./MainConfig/MAINCSS.css">
while the subfolders in langages (Gr and En) 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../MainConfig/MAINCSS.css">

I have tried changing to "MainConfig/MAINCSS.css" and "MyTestWebsite/MainConfig/MAINCSS.css" but it had the same result

The browser console show -> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Please can you edit the question and put the information in there. It is better to edit the question so that people don't have to go searching through the comments.

Comment: Is the file structure I have constructed accurate? Please correct any cases, as file names are *case-sensitive*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contact the support and the code was correct, although there was server-side problem which the support fixed.

Thank you guys for taking time to help !!!